# No mouse or keyboard until password entered

Tags: python, bash, security

I'm trying to secure a Pi, and one of the things I'm keen on implementing - if possible - is that whatever input that comes in via the USB ports goes nowhere unless it's a 6-digit password (or longer) that's saved on the device.

So if someone plugs a keyboard into one of the ports and presses the Windows key or ctrl-alt-del or whatever it does nothing unless they type 817401 into the keyboard, then all the keys are available  and after 5 mins idle it goes back to disabling everything but the numbers.

Seems simple enough, but would this be possible with Python or a simple shell script?

Comment: Not Pi specific.  Any solution would be common to all Linux boxes.

Comment: Welcome. *"Would this be possible with Python or a simple shell script"* -> No, you need to implement that in the kernel.  This is not trivial, and as joan points out, it is a task specific to linux systems with USB ports, a much more general category than "raspberry pi".  Try our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), probably you want to ask if there is anything like this already available.